# Chrome Extension Help - Send data to file to display notification

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I am creating a Chrome Extension, and I've reached a point where I want to create a desktop notification that links to a forum thread.  I'm using jQuery to retrieve data from a server, which contains the ID of the thread.  Since the only way to do HTML in desktop notifications is to put it in a separate file, I need some way to pass the data onto the external notification file.

I've looked into message passing (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html), but the data doesn't stay while the notification file is called.

Are there any ideas?

Thanks very much in advance!  It is greatly appreciated.

Carl L.

Answer (score 1):

From a notification you can call your background page directly:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().getCurrentThreadId();
```

You can also use URL parameters (which you would need to parse on notification's side):

```
webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification("notification.html?threadid=100");
```